# Flutter - After form validation helperText property can't be changed with bloc pattern

Tags: forms, validation, flutter

I have a validation Form something like this:

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget{

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
  ... widgets ...
  child: Form(
    key: _formKey,     // type: GlobalKey<FormState>()
     ... more widgets ...
       child: TextFormField(
         _helperText = "Some text",
         validator: (String text){
           return "Error text!";
         }
         decoration: InputDecoration(
            ...
            _helperText: helperText   // I mutate the helperText somewhere else and rebuild the
            ...                       // widget tree if something notifies it to do so ...
         )
     ...
     MaterialButton(
       onPressed: _formKey.currentState.validate(),
     )
     ...
```

Before validation helperText's text is "Some text" but after I validate it, it gets the "Error text!" and becomes red. So far so good. I manipulate the helperText property without any issue with the bloc pattern (so in this particular case I use StatelessWidget instead of StatefulWidget and setState() - but I don't think that would solve the problem), but after validation (if it's an error), changing the helperText has no visual effect on the TextFormField widget helperText property.

Note: If I would `return null;` istead of `return "Error text!";` the helperText won't be in an 'error' state so mutating the helperText property in that case would work as normal. The problem occurs when a value other then `null` is returned.

So what can I do to validate the form, and even after that - despite the fact that it is an error - I'm still able to edit the helperText and also the TextFormField decoration colors and helperText color, etc. ?

Sorry for the minimalist example but maybe you have an idea or you faced a similar issue.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some research it turned out that there is an errorText property under InputDecoration which seems to override (not literally but visually) the helperText property if it is not null and that's why I don't see the changes made in helperText.

So one solution would be to set it's value to null. Then the changes in helperText will be visible again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use error text inside

```
 TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
       errorText: validate ? "Enter email" : null
)
)
```

Here validate is a boolean value which is going to tell whether the error text must be shown or not.

Comment: My idea was very similar but somehow it does not work after it gets a value other than null. After that I somehow can't get rid of that error text. I don't really understand why...

Comment: You need to check the condition based on the value using a TextEditingController and use setState() accordingly it will work.